# how can i get label value in laravel controller

Tags: html, laravel-4

Here is my html code :

```
<label value="2" name="myLabel">Hello</label>
```

Here is my laravel controller code :

```
$temp=Input::get("myLabel");
```

I am not able to get the value of this label as this is not an input type control, please let me know the answer.

Thanks

Comment: why you want to do this? anyway you need javascript

Comment: i know how to get the value using javascript, but i want to get the value in Laravel controller.

Comment: I don't think `value` is a valid attribute for `<label>`: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-label-element

Answer (score 1):

Use Hiddenfield with of label and set the value of that hiddenfield equalto the label.

Answer (score 0):

try to use id attribute in your label. It works on me. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp

Comment: This answer could be better if you would share a code example.